# Complex Integral over an Astroid

Tags: complex-analysis

The question asks us to compute the complex integral:

$$\int \frac{\text dz}{(z^{2}-1)^{2}(z-3)^{2}}$$

Over the positively oriented astroid: $$x^{\frac{2}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}=2^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

I know that we are supposed to use the Residue theorem to evaluate the integral, but I have absolutely no idea what to do with this path of integration.

Are we supposed to parametrize it in the complex plane? (How to do that?)

Thanks.

Comment: This is a straightforward application of the Cauchy residue theorem:  it doesn't matter what the path is, so long as it is closed and does not intersect any singularities.

Comment: Ok, I will go ahead and try it with that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, since Cauchy's theorem hypothesis holds for a suitable neighbourhood of the curve, the path of integration doesn't matter as long as the path you choose has the same singularities *inside* and doesn't pass through any of them.

Observe that the function $\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}$ is holomorphic in any such neighbourhood (because 3 is outside this open set). To finish, remember Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives:
$$ 
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2i\pi}\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\operatorname{d}z.
$$
So, putting everything together:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}\right)'\left.\right\rvert_{z=1} = -\frac{2}{(z-3)^3}\left.\right\rvert_{z=1}= \frac{1}{4}= \frac{1!}{2i\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{\frac{1}{(z-3)^2}}{(z-1)^2}dz.
$$